# Image Encoding/Decoding using python

Tags: python, image-processing

I was given a list of string which represents an encoded image in a csv file. The string previously were encoded from the images which were exported from MS SQL Server 'image' column.

The task is to figure out which encoding is used so the strings can be decoded to an image again.

I've have posted one of the string here:

```
https://pastebin. com/BfjdTqdr
```

May I know how I can approach this problem using python.

I apologize in advance if this does not make a good question. You may leave a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: The link does not work (may be due to firewall) and seems misformed. A good old hex/ascii dump of the first 32 bytes would help to check for GIF, PNG and other fixed header formats. The problem as I understand it, is unrelated to programming: it must be solved before you have a chance to start something, no matter which language you use. The question type "how could I program that and that" is typically considered off-topic, if you don't have any specific code and run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an incomplete JPEG image as identified by the `0xff` `0xd8` JPEG signature at the start.

You can convert it back into an image using `xxd` with the *"reverse from plain dump"* (`-r -p`) options as follows:

```
xxd -r -p YOURFILE > a.jpg
```

[image]

I think I removed the `0x` from the first two bytes of the file, IIRC.

---

If you really want to write some Python, this works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

# Slurp in entire file
with open('lc.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

# Convert to binary
b=bytes.fromhex(content)

# Write to output file
with open("recovered.jpg", "wb") as jpeg_file:
    jpeg_file.write(b)
```